# JSON POST data interpreted differently between IE and FF

Tags: javascript

I am using valum's fileuploader http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ to upload a file.  Upon complete (i.e. onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){}), I get the following POST response as viewed by Firebug.

```
{"id":"13","filename":"Brighton\u2019s Rock Collection.docx","size":"12 KB","date":"07\/18\/2012","time":"09:34:35 AM","icon":"<img src=\"lib\/stdimages\/icons\/32x32\/doc.png\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\" \/>","errors":[]}
```

Next, I want to append a row to a table with the new data.  Works great with Firefox, but when IE8 is used, the icon's don't show up.  I don't know a good way to troubleshoot IE, so I just do alert(responseJSON.icon);.  Instead of what I expect, I get:

```
<IMG src='"lib/stdimages/icons/32x32/doc.png"' width='"32"' height='"32"' />
```

The img was changed to IMG and I get single quotes around my attributes.  Well, that is probably why the icons are not showing up.  Can anyone tell me why this is happening, and what I need to do to prevent it.

Thank you

Comment: I later tried bypassing the valum's script, and just used jQuery's post(), and img wasn't capitalized and the extra quotes were not added.  How can I test what IE is receiving?  Maybe some sort of strip tags either server or client side would help?

Comment: how did you parse your json? did you use eval or JSON.parse?

Comment: @NSF.  Server-side, use PHP's json_encode().  Client-side, valums's fileupload plugin uses eval().